# Does a netherite blocks in a beacon make the beacon more powerful?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I wanted to know if you can use a netherite ingot vs an iron ingot would affect anything in the beacon?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a netherite ingot to activate a beacon instead of an iron ingot, but **no, the beacon effect won't be stronger**.

From the [official wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon#Powers):

> Once the beacon is emitting a beam, it can then be fed one iron ingot, gold ingot, emerald, diamond, or netherite ingot to select the status effects given to players within range of the beacon. This is done through the beacon's GUI, displayed by pressing use while looking at the beacon block. **It doesn't matter which of the items** is fed into the beacon.

Comment: Thank you for this! You just saved me a netherite ingot.

Comment: @Anthony Good you didn't start building netherite block base. It also doesn't make the beacon stronger than other materials :)